# variable not setting textview text

Tags: swift3

I have a baffling situation to me in which I set the variable passageText to a certain value, but it doesn't update the UITextView.

Here is my controller code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class FavoritesDetailsViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var referenceLabel: UILabel!

//I've confirmed that the UITextView is connected to this outlet
@IBOutlet weak var passageText: UITextView!

var specifiedFavorite : String = ""

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    referenceLabel.text? = specifiedFavorite

    print("The FavoritesDetailsViewController viewDidLoad")

    print("The Value of variable specifiedFavorite sent from segue is: \(specifiedFavorite)")

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Passages")

    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "reference == %@", specifiedFavorite)

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {

        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        print("fetch request was successful")

        if results.count > 0 {

            print("The number of results returned is: \(results.count)")

            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

                print("We got results!")

                if let returnedText = result.value(forKey: "passagetext") as? String {

                    self.passageText.text! = returnedText

                    print("This is the text from the passageText textview: \(self.passageText.text!)")

                }

            }

        }

    } catch {

        print("Couldn't fetch results")

    }    
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("The FavoritesDetailsViewController viewDidLoad")

    print("The Value of variable specifiedFavorite sent from segue is: \(specifiedFavorite)")

    print(specifiedFavorite)
}
}
```

Here is the output of my logs:

```
The Value of variable specifiedFavorite sent from segue is: Genesis 3:1
fetch request was successful
The number of results returned is: 1
We got results!
This is the text from the passageText textview: The Fall
Now  the serpent was more crafty than any other beast....
```

So it appears that the UITextView text named "passageText" has been set properly.

```
self.passageText.text! = returnedText
```

I know that failure to add the .text is often a newbie error that I think I avoided here. I've also confirmed that the UITextView is connected to my IBOutlet. I'm just not sure why the UI doesn't update to the new value. I could use some fresh eyes on this.

Comment: Try to declare `passageText` as strong (delete `weak`)

Comment: @vadian - I tried declaring passageText by deleting the keyword weak, but that did not address the issue. Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering if this has something to do with the fact that I'm assigning this value inside a loop even though I anticipate there only being one item returned in the results array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll chalk this one up to experience. The issue was that my auto layout constraints were not set properly so the UITextView was not visible in the UI. This can be easy to overlook because in Xcode the textview is visible. But don't ignore those red lines and Xcode warnings! They indicate problems that even if the app compiles and runs, could impact the proper function as in my case. Hope someone learns from my mistake.